# I am trying to get the values that i inserted in the database dynamically but I can't get the value

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to get the values that i inserted in the database dynamically but I can't get the value. here my code

```
     String[] SchoolName = request.getParameterValues("shoolname");
     String[] DateFrom = request.getParameterValues("Dateform");
     String[] DateTo = request.getParameterValues("Datato");
     String[] DiscriptDetails = request.getParameterValues("Dscript");
```

this for insert data and its working well.

```
 for ( int i = 0 ; i < SchoolName.length;++i ) {
        educatiodetails edu = new educatiodetails();
        edu.setSchoolName(SchoolName[i]);
        edu.setDateFrom(DateFrom[i]);
        edu.setDateTo(DateTo[i]);
        edu.setDiscriptDetails(DiscriptDetails[i]);


                 EducatiIMP education = new EducatiIMP();
                 education.addEducation(edu);
                 HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

//here I am trying to get values

```
                addEducation.getList();
               educatiodetails educat =education.geteducatiodetails(SchoolName[i]); 
session.setAttribute("educat",educat);
                   }
                  }
```

and here my jsp that should be view the data for the user.

```
<% educatiodetails eduact = (educatiodetails) (session.getAttribute("educat"));%>
                  <% if (eduact != null ) { %>
                  <%= eduact.getSchoolName()%>

<%}%>
```

Comment: also I tried the foreach and I get the same result. I con't more than one data for each textbox values.